# alertcondition(condition, title, message) Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I want to create a costume alert using Pine Script. I am new at this and I need help.
I want to trigger an alert after a shape appears on a Invite-only script (TBO) Trending Break Out and after  RSI 7 is greater than 80. I found a similar code, which you can find it below, but I can't figure out how to include the condition for the TBO. Please see script below and let me know if you can help me. Thank you

```
//@version=3
```

study(title="Multiple alert criteria - example 1", overlay=false)

rsiValue = rsi(close, 12)

// Set up alert
alertcondition(condition=
     (rsiValue > 50) and (close > ema(close, 25)),
     message="RSI > 50 with EMA uptrend")

// Plot values
plot(series=rsiValue, color=teal)

Answer (score 0):

If the script is invite-only, then you don't have access to the code and we're not going to reverse-engineer the script for you here.